# divisible 2nd cohomolgy group $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z}G)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory

Recall that a (nontrivial) abelian group $A$ is called *divisible* if the multiplication by $n$ is surjection $A\to A$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$.

My question is the following.

**Is there a countable discrete group $G$ in the class $\mathcal{G}$ such that $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z}G)$ is not divisible?**

where the class $\mathcal{G}$ contains the following groups: groups with Kazhdan's property (T), any infinite non-amenable group $G$ of the form $G=G_1\times G_2$, etc., and any group in $\mathcal{G}$ is assumed to be non-amenable with zero first $L^2$-Betti number.

Comment: Could you define precisely the class $\mathcal{G}$? or your question does not make sense.

Comment: Also "infinite non-amenable group $G_1\times G_2$" precisely means "infinite non-amenable group", which most likely is not what you mean.

Comment: @YCor, I do not have a precise description of the class of $\mathcal{G}$, but you can think this is the class of the group which satisfies $\mathbb{T}$-valued co cycle super-rigidity for its Bernoulli shift action. So, if possible, I expect an example from (T) groups.

Comment: There is a topological Interpretation of that cohomology: when G is the fundamental group of a compact space M, then $$H^*(G,ZG)=H_c^*(\widetilde{M})$$

Comment: where the right hand side means cohomology with Compact Support of the universal covering. Not sure whether that helps, though.

Comment: @ThiKu, thanks, I learned this interpretation from Brown's GTM book, but do not know how to use it.

Comment: The first examples of a (torsionfree) Kazhdan Group are perhaps (torsionfree, finite-index subgroups of) higher rank lattices like $SL(n,Z), n\ge 3$. In this case however $\widetilde{M}$ is homeomorphic to $R^N$, so $H^2(G,ZG)=0$.

Comment: @ThiKu your M must be aspherical.

Comment: @Thiku, yes, it is a result of Borel-Serre. Do you know any example such that the 2nd cohomology group is finitely generated? Of course, G is assumed to have (T) and this would solve my question.

Comment: You would have to find a space $M$ with $\pi_1M$ als desired and whose universal covering is (weakly contractible but) not homeomorphic to $R^n, n\not=2$. This doesn't look like an easy problem but perhaps I'm just unimaginative.